# JSON não chega completo ao enviar por Bundle

Tags: java, android, json, bundle

Estou tentando receber pegar o retorno de um push no android através do Bundle, porém estou tendo algum problema ao realizar `bundle.getString("Message");` pois o mesmo não pega toda a minha resposta que está em formato JSON, segue o formato da mensagem:

```
 Message=[
  {
    "Key": "type",
    "Value": "0"
  },
  {
    "Key": "msg",
    "Value": "valor"
  }
]
```

o `bundle.getString("Message");` trás pra mim a resposta somente até.

```
[
      {
        "Key": "type"
```

O restante é ignorado. Alguma ideia do que pode ser este problema?

Comment: Tem como você mostrar a forma com que você está passando esse JSON ao Bundle?

Comment: http://gcm-alert.appspot.com/ envio através desse link e no campo message adiciono o json acima.

Comment: Ok, você se certificou se a mensagem está sendo passada inteira?

Answer (score 1):

Você está tentando passar informações de uma Activity para outra? Se esse for o caso então faça de acordo com o informado, caso não seja, isso servirá de ajuda.

Primeiramente na sua Activity que enviará os dados você deverá passas os valores em **String** ou alguma classe **Parcelable**, pois não é possível transmitir objetos do tipo JSON pelo Bundle.

Na Activity que irá enviar você pode fazer o seguinte:

```
JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject();
try {
    jsonObject.put("type", 0);
    jsonObject.put("msg", "valor");
} catch (JSONException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
String Message = jsonObject.toString();
Intent intent = (new Intent(this, SuaActivity2.class));
intent.putExtra("Message", Message);
startActivity(intent);
```

E na Activity que irá receber os dados:

```
String Message = bundle.getString("Message");
try {
    JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(Message);
} catch (JSONException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```